# R shiny reactive input based on choice

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny UI that I cannot figure out how to get reactive text box to appear as desired and for that information to be then saved to the global environment. Below is my code and pictures to assist in what I am trying to achieve.

```
#shiny application
library(shiny)


words <- c("age", "gender", "income", "education")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Custom Raking"),
     mainPanel(
       
      column(5,
             h3("Test"),
             lapply(words, function(x){
               selectInput(inputId = paste0('test_',x), label = x, 
                           choices = c("user-entered", "to-total", "to-control", "to-test"),
                           selected = "to-total")})
             ),
      
      column(5,
             h3("Control"),
             lapply(words, function(y){
               selectInput(inputId = paste0('control_',y), label = y, 
                           choices = c("user-entered", "to-total", "to-control", "to-test"),
                           selected = "to-total")})   
             )
      
      )
    )


server <- function(input, output) {

  observe({
    choices_x <- lapply(words, function(x){
     input[[paste0('test_',x)]]})
    # Assign the list of choices to the global environment
    assign("choices_x", choices_x, envir = .GlobalEnv)
   
  })
  
  observe({
    choices_y <- lapply(words, function(y){
      input[[paste0('control_',y)]]})
    assign("choices_y", choices_y, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server,options=c(launch.browser = .rs.invokeShinyPaneViewer))
```

Here is what the current UI looks like:

[image]

I would like it to have an additional box for user to enter information if the selection is "user-entered"
like so:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a `conditionalPanel` to add your `textInput`s

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Custom Raking"),
  mainPanel(
    column(
      5,
      h3("Test"),
      lapply(words, function(x) {
        tagList(
          selectInput(
            inputId = paste0("test_", x), label = x,
            choices = c("user-entered", "to-total", "to-control", "to-test"),
            selected = "to-total"
          ),
          conditionalPanel(
            paste0("input.test_", x, " === 'user-entered'"),
            textInput(paste0("test_", x, "_text"), label = NULL)
          )
        )
      })
    ),
    column(
      5,
      h3("Control"),
      lapply(words, function(y) {
        tagList(
          selectInput(
            inputId = paste0("control_", y), label = y,
            choices = c("user-entered", "to-total", "to-control", "to-test"),
            selected = "to-total"
          ),
          conditionalPanel(
            paste0("input.control_", y, " === 'user-entered'"),
            textInput(paste0("test_", y, "_text"), label = NULL)
          )
        )
      })
    )
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: hm seems to work unfortunately I need to not specify it only for age. The 'words' input will change and not always be the same. I need it to pop up with a text box when ANY of the drop-downs are selected as user-entered.

Comment: maybe:     ```conditionalPanel(paste0("input.test_", x,"===" ,"'user-entered'"),textInput(paste0("test_", x,"_text"), label = NULL)}``` instead.. hm but now how to save those to my global env.

Comment: Basically you figured it out yourself. (: But see my edit.